# Using Observable in Kotlin to parse a API response

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin

I am trying to parse the data from the server to my mobile device and I am using `Rx` , `Kotlin` , `retrofit` for this

**ApiInterface.kt**

```
@GET("api/v1/admin/class/getUsers/learner/{classId}")
    fun getStudentsRx(
        @Header("access_token") accessToken: String,
        @Path("classId") apiKey: String
    ): Observable<StudentResultResponse>
```

**I am trying to subscribe as follows:**

```
 private fun getServerDataDisposable(dataService: ApiInterface): Disposable {
        return dataService.getStudentsRx(accessToken,classId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object: DisposableSingleObserver<List<StudentModel>>(), Observer<StudentResultResponse> {

                override fun onSuccess(movies: List<StudentModel>) {
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {

                }

                override fun onChanged(t: StudentResultResponse?) {
                    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }

            })
    }
```

**I am getting error:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check below answer...

```
private fun getServerDataDisposable(dataService: ApiInterface): Disposable {
    return dataService.getStudentsRx(accessToken,classId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object: DisposableSingleObserver<StudentResultResponse>(), Observer<StudentResultResponse> {

                override fun onSuccess(t: StudentResultResponse) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

                override fun onComplete() {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

                override fun onNext(t: StudentResultResponse) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

            })
}
```